# materializecss: card in materialize

Tags: android, cordova, materialize

Is it a good way to use card in [Materialize CSS](http://materializecss.com/) as on click card popups it used for values to edit and save and it pops back i'm using it for android application using a Phonegap.

The real problem is i was not able to use modal in Materialize CSS as this is not responding well in my emulator.modal is pop up's without clicking.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime this will be happened when you use `<a>` tag. Instead of using`<a>` tag use `<button>` tag. I have added sample html code snippet. Try this.

HTML

```
<button data-target="modal1" class="btn modal-trigger">Click ME</button>

<div id="modal1" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <h4>POP UP</h4>
    </div>  
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {            
        $('.modal-trigger').leanModal();
    });
</script>
```

Full Code in single html page.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Select</title>
 <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.3/css/materialize.min.css">
 <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
</head>

<body>
  
 <button data-target="modal1" class="btn modal-trigger">Click ME</button>

    <div id="modal1" class="modal" style="width: 360px; max-height: 100%; height: 50%;" >
     <div class="modal-content">
         <h4>POP UP</h4>
     </div>  
    </div>      

     
 <!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
 <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.3/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function () {   
            $('.modal-trigger').leanModal();
        });
 </script>

</body>
</html>
```